# Format datetime with Time, SimpleDatetimeFormat, Calendar, GregorianCalendar

Tags: java, android, datetime

I would like to learn ways to format a given datetime

I know only this

```
            now=new Time(Time.getCurrentTimezone());
            now.setToNow();                 
            String t=now.format("%H:%M");
```

I would like to know how to output e.g `03:30 PM`, `2014-3-20 15:30`, `Sun,3/15/2014 15:30`
`Sunday, March 15 2014 03:30 AM` etc

I'd like to use Time class of android.text.format.Time to format my hours into i.e `3:30 AM`. document of this class on developer site doesn't provide any details on the format string method

**Document of this format string is found here**
https://php.net/strftime

Comment: Read the documentation: [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). Pay attention to the examples.

Answer (score 1):

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(new Date());
```

you can change the separator by yourself

Comment: if I have only Time object, how can I change it into SimpleDateFormat ?

Answer (score 0):

It can be easier:

```
String t=time.format("Time: "+"%T"+" Date: "+"%D");
```